# Cant create shot in Dribbble

Tags: php

I need your help with this:

I try to create a shot in Dribbly but get the error message.

I did it like described in the documentation(http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/shots/#create-a-shot). This is my code:

```
$url = "http://www.rodos-palace.gr/uploads/images/509.jpg"; 
    print_r($drib->create_shot('shottitle', $url)); 



public function create_shot($title, $image, $description = false)
{
    $query = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'image' => $image
    );

    if ($description) {
        $query['description'] = $description;
    }

//   print_r("<br>crearing_shot-> ".__LINE__);

$query['access_token'] = $this->access_token;


return $this->curl_post_shot($this->short_api, $query);

//    return $this->curl_post_shot($this->short_api . "?" . 'access_token=' . $this->access_token, http_build_query($query));
}


public function curl_post_shot($url, $post)
{


    $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data");

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,

        /*,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false*/
    ));

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $information = curl_getinfo($curl);

    if( ($resp = curl_exec($curl)) === false )
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    else
    {
       // echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
    }

    //echo "Check HTTP status code >>>>";
    // Check HTTP status code
    if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
      switch ($information = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
        case 200:  # OK
          break;
        default:
          { /*echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";*/}
      }
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    print_r("<br>crearing_shot-> ".__LINE__);

    echo "<pre>";

    var_dump($information);
    print_r("<br>----------------------------<br>");

    print_r($headers);
    return $resp;
}
```

and this is the error:

> {   "message": "Validation failed.",   "errors": [
>       {
>         "attribute": "image",
>         "message": "file is required"
>       }   ] }

beside this, I try to do it with the image real path and with the PHP `$_FILES` and the result is the same.

please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot verify, because I do not have an uploader account, I recommend using the cURL file class to upload a file. There are multiple ways to to this, but since you use OOP you should try this:

```
public function create_shot($title, $image, $description = false)
{
    $query = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'image' => new CURLFile($image), // $image is the absolute path to the image file
    );

    if ($description) {
        $query['description'] = $description;
    }

    $query['access_token'] = $this->access_token;

    return $this->curl_post_shot($this->short_api, $query);
}
```

You will find details in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) about the file upload.